# how to make magento website avaliable only for registered users?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, magento-1, login, ce-1.9.2.2

Is that possible when a user visit on the website, its ask for login and then after login user will access the website. So basically only login user will access the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added below php code in your `theme/template/page/html/head.phtml` file:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    //not logged in
    $cnt = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); // return controller name

    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName(); // return action name

    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); // return routes name

    if ($cnt != "account" && $action != "account" && $action != "login") {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('customer/account/login')->sendResponse();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can feel free to up vote my answer thanks.

Comment: How can i set, the registered customer only use the contact form.

Answer (score 0):

There are several modules available for what you want to achieve:

- http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/05/15/a-magento-module-to-require-login-on-your-store/
- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/require-login.html

The idea is basically to use an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch` event, check if the user is logged in and if the customer is not logged in, redirect to the login/register page.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to use any extension or module. Could you please explain, how would I setup "controller_action_predispatch" in default Magento.

Comment: To be honest your last comment shows the urgent need for an extension for your purpose and not a hack like it looks.

Comment: @MaceLong check the github repo from the first link I posted, the module is free

Comment: How can i set, the registered customer only use the contact form.